# How can I zoom in&out of a displayed Julia output Image in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

In my jupyter notebook I'm computing and displaying images using the `Images` package.
Is there a way that I can press a hotkey combination + mouse so I could zoom into the images i'm getting on the output?

For instance, I have this cell:

```
using Plots, Images, HTTP
r = HTTP.request("GET", "http://eeweb.poly.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/image/lena_gray.raw")
img = reshape(r.body, 512, 512)
Gray.(img/255.)
```

Can I zoom into the displayed image on the output of this Cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Jupyter, but [ImageView](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl) supports many different kinds of interactivity.

Comment: does ImageView support viewing within the notebook and not as a separate window?

Comment: No, it uses GTK so it has to be an extra window.